# Highcharts dataLabels shadows

Tags: highcharts

When `useHTML` is set to `false`, is it possible to set a text shadow with similar parameters as is possible with the `text-shadow` CSS property?  In particular, can you offset the shadow relative to the text (e.g. to the lower right), or is it always just an outline around the text?  The [highcharts docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.style) suggest that it's only possible to set an amount and colour (e.g. `"textOutline": "1px contrast"`), or in other words that you can't offset the "shadow"... it really is just an "outline" when `useHTML` is set to `false`.  (There are reasons why I cannot just set `useHTML` to `true` in some situations.)

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure that the documented options will work, the others are experimental. You should use `shadow` property or `shadow` method to add shadow to your data labels:

```
            shadow: {
                color: 'red',
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: 0,
                width: 10
            }
```

API:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#shadow

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.shadow

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bcy6hwLq/

You should also consider using styled mode: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

Comment: This seems to apply to the shadow for the *box around the label*, rather than the shadow for the text of the label itself.

Comment: Hi drmrbrewer, yes you are right, but does not it still solve your problem? What exactly effect do you want to achieve?